# Force Webpack 4 to import cjs only and never esm with typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, package.json, redux-toolkit, tsconfig

App built on `webpack@4.43.0`; TypeScript 4.2.4;

Trying install and use `@reduxjs/toolkit` on app will produce build errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'immer' in './node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist'
```

**How to disable importing esm modules from "module" path of libraries package.json and use only "main" entry point in webpack?**

package.json of `@reduxjs/toolkit`

```
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/redux-toolkit.umd.min.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
```

our configs:
**tsconfig.json**

```
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "esnext",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HappyPackConfig = new HappyPack({
  id: 'ts',
  threads: 2,
  loaders: [
    {
      path: 'ts-loader',
      query: { happyPackMode: true },
      options: {
        transpileOnly: true,
      },
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = {
  node: {
    net: 'mock',
  },
  entry: ['whatwg-fetch', './src/index.tsx'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.[contenthash].js',
    publicPath: '/',
    globalObject: 'this',
  },
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'inline-source-map' : false,
  devServer: {
    https: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: /node_modules/,
    },
  },
  optimization: { ... },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /\/node_modules/,
        use: { loader: 'happypack/loader?id=ts' },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**package.json** does not contain `"type": "module"`
and we are not using `babel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding following parameters to `webpack.config.js` helps in my case:

```
module.exports = {
/* ... */
resolve: {
    /* ... */
    mainFields: ['browser', 'main'],
  },
};
```

Comment: It would be great to mention why (see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemainfields): `this option will determine which fields in its package.json are checked` therefore you want to make sure the "module" field is not listed.